# Rim of a mesh is staying rigid in sculpt mode

Tags: mesh, modifiers, solidify-modifier, sculpt-mode, brushes

I have a mesh which can be deformed by the grab brush without any problems except the outer rim of the mesh. For an example, here I added a plain plane and just switched to the scuplt mode grabbing in once. No modifiers nothing, but the rim of the plane stays the same as the rest of the mesh gets deformed.

[image]

When I am going to add a solidfy modifier and apply it, I can manipulate the new mesh in the usual way.

Comment: How many subdivisions/vertices do you have on the plane? When you grab, it will just move vertices within the influence of the grab brush so if there aren't that many vertices and you've grabbed near the centre of the plane the rim is unlikely to be moved. I'd be inclined to use Edit mode with proportional editing turned on for that.

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you for your comment. The reason you mentioned is unfortunately not the problem. Working with the Proportional editing just works fine but I like to follow my sculpting workflow and therefore I need it to work as it should. Strangely it did work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by appending all objects to a blend file. So it was some kind of global setting (or bug) which had nothing to do with the objects themself.